# Azure - Load balancing/HA - two PIPs

Tags: azure, high-availability, failover, kamailio

I am trying to set up high availability for two servers (Kamailio) in Azure. The problem is - both servers have to use instance-level public IP addresses [as described here](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/). They are used to bypass the limitation on the number of endpoints per vm (we are using around 50000 of those as opposed to the allowed 150).

The problem is that neither traffic manager (routes to endpoint) nor vm load-balancing (limits endpoints) seem to be able to achieve that.

Does anyone have experience with this scenario and/or can advise a method that does not rely on DNS failover?

Thanks!

Comment: Surprised Traffic Manager can't handle this as it can balance between Azure and non-Azure endpoints.

Comment: Where did you see that? All I have in my traffic manager are Azure Websites and Azure Cloud Services.

Comment: You can only configure "External Endpoints" as they are called using PowerShell. See http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-traffic-manager-external-endpoints-and-weighted-round-robin-via-powershell/

Comment: @user3521621 can you share more information on yoru azure setup relating to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by load-balancing Kamailio through load-balanced endpoints on a VIP, with RTPEngine advertising the PIP so that the RTP traffic passes through unobstructed.